# Why does document.getElementById('files') return null?

Tags: javascript, html

The code below simply didn't work.

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

reported by firebug that this getElementById is null but I added a text and it is working.....

it seems the codes are correct...

updates :this is the html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect,   false);
   document.getElementById('username');
   function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   alert('i am called');
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

 // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
 var output = [];
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
              f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
              f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
              '</li>');}
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="file" id="files"  />
<div id="list"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "but I added a text and it is working"?

Comment: @JobSmith: give us more code. Your snippet doesn't give us a broad enough overview for us to know what can go wrong and where. Where is this JS snippet in your document, and when does it get executed? Is the HTML snippet statically loaded with the page, or is it dynamically created? Show us more code.

Comment: @Claudio Redi  I added<input type="text" id="username" /> it works

Comment: @JobSmith: how does that have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: @JobSmith: let's backtrack... **What are you trying to do**, overall, with this code and your program in general?

Comment: sorry guys...i am not good at edtting..sorry for waiting...i updated the codes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you're trying to get an element, while the element itself is not loaded yet. You need to move the JavaScript down, after the element, or run the code as a callback when the page has finish loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    document.getElementById('username');
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {

        alert('i am called');

        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
              '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: It's generally a good practice to include any JavaScript at the bottom of the <body> just before the closing </body> tag for optimization.